# Backbone comparator sort by different field types

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a collection that I want sorted by three different fields. One of these fields is a boolean, the other is an integer, and the third is a string.

I want my collection of teams to be sorted by the organization_id they belong to first, and then sorted by an is_primary flag (the boolean), and finally I want them to be alphabetized.

So ideally my collection would look like this when it's done:

- Team C (is_primary) (org_id 1)
- Team A (org_id 1)
- Team B (org_id 1)
- Team D (is_primary) (org_id 2)
- Team A (org_id 2)
- Team B (org_id 2)
- Team C (org_id 2)

Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried

```
comparator: (team) -> [team.get('organization_id'), team.get('name'), team.get('is_primary')]
```

But that doesn't seem to actually work. Can anyone provide some help here for me?

Comment: _A comparator can be defined as a `sortBy` (pass a function that takes a single argument), as a `sort` (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments), or as a string indicating the attribute to `sort by`_ ([ref.](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator))

Comment: So basically, there isn't an easy way to do what I want to do?

Comment: Obviously, no. Define `sortBy` or `sort` callback. This is not so hard as seem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Backbone.Model,
  sortOrder: ['organization_id', 'is_primary', 'name'],
  comparator: function(a, b) {
    var order = 0;
    _.each(this.sortOrder, function(prop){
      var aa = a.get(prop), bb = b.get(prop);
      aa = _.isBoolean(aa) ? !aa : aa; // true is greater than false,
      bb = _.isBoolean(bb) ? !bb : bb; // but we want to reverse that
      order = aa === bb ? 0 : aa > bb ? 1 : -1;
      return !order;
    });
    return order;
  }
});

var c = new Collection([
  { is_primary: false, organization_id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { is_primary: false, organization_id: 2, name: 'A' },
  { is_primary: false, organization_id: 1, name: 'B' },
  { is_primary: false, organization_id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { is_primary: true,  organization_id: 1, name: 'C' },
  { is_primary: false, organization_id: 2, name: 'C' },
  { is_primary: true,  organization_id: 2, name: 'D' }
]);

c.each(function(t){
  console.log('Team %s %s(org_id %d)', t.get('name'), t.get('is_primary') ? '(is_primary) ' : '', t.get('organization_id'));
});

// Outputs:
Team C (is_primary) (org_id 1)
Team A (org_id 1)
Team B (org_id 1)
Team D (is_primary) (org_id 2)
Team A (org_id 2)
Team B (org_id 2)
Team C (org_id 2)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me :/ Nothing is sorted at all after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own problem by doing the following:

```
@teams.comparator = (team) ->
  [team.get('organization_id'), if team.get('is_primary') then '0' else '1' + (team.get('name').toLowerCase())]
@teams.sort()
```